# Accessing pages field in Kentico database

Tags: sql, kentico

I have a pages field inside a page called PageDetail that i want to access in the database. 
When i go to the table PageDetail I can see the column but its always null.

I need to acces these values for an integration.

Thankyou in advance,

Arne

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail here. This is a field added to a custom page type? If so, you're looking in that page type's dedicated database table? If so, do you have versioning enabled on this Kentico instance?

Comment: Arne, are you specifically talking about a field with a data type of 'Pages'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is that `Pages` field values are not stored on the page types underlying table.  They create an *ad-hoc relationship name* to store the data that you select, so the actual value is stored elsewhere.

If you take a look in the two tables `CMS_RelationshipName` and `CMS_Relationship`, you should find the data that you're looking for.  If you look at `View_CMS_RelationshipJoined`, you should be able to work out the query that you need to pull out the data for your integration.

Comment: Hey Matt, I don't believe the OP is talking about relationships at all, he's simply asking how he can get the page data out of the database.

Comment: The OP makes mention of a 'pages field', which behind the scenes is an ad-hoc relationship.  Best info/description I can find on it is here: https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/defining-website-content-structure/page-types/advanced-content-modeling.  As you might guess, searching for 'Pages' on DevNet has a reasonable amount of results. :)  If you create a Pages field, it will always be null in the underlying table.

Comment: Totally missed that one Matt! See they updated the documentation already too.

Comment: Wow - that's a quick turnaround on documentation updates! :)

Comment: @mnield That's exactly what i needed. Thankyou for the info!